# VS 2008 text visualizer appears broken

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-ce, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging an application for the MC75A device. Earlier, I was able to use the text visualizer to capture the contents of a StringBuilder that traced the calls to a web service. The contents were initially truncated at the start or restart of the application (if ( trace.Length > 0 ) trace.Length = 0;). As each call was made to the web service, the XML input and XML output were appended to the contents of the StringBuilder.

Until recently the text visualizer of the VS 2008 debugger worked well.  I would capture the contents of the StringBuilder as text, copy the contents to the clipboard, and paste the contents into an XML file that VS 2008 formatted on paste. Now, as soon as I click on the text visualizer in the debugger drop down, VS 2008 stops interacting, requiring the termination of VS 2008 by the Task Manager.

I'm not sure what changed or the conditions that may be causing this behavior. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Gus

Comment: Attach a second copy of VS to the frozen copy, click pause, and look at the call stack.

Comment: [In a sleep, wait, or join] unfortunately there is only an address trace following (no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame - the source code cannot be displayed).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am unsure as to why, but Visual Studio 2008 is now working as expected.